# FTP_INCORRECT_HOST_KEY in N/SFTP Module

Tags: sftp, netsuite

While creating the connection from NetSuite to SFTP using N/SFTP module i'm facing an error states:

> "FTP_INCORRECT_HOST_KEY","message":"Provided host key does not match
>   remote server's fingerprint."

I have tried checking with my server team but no hope. Can any one suggest me how to resolve this or how can i get an authorized finger print host key from server.

I have tried with Suitescript 2.0 module (N/SFTP) with the help of the tool mentioned below.

https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/suitescript-2-0-sftp-tool/

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
define(['N/sftp', 'N/file', 'N/runtime'],function(sftp, file,runtime) {  

    function execute(context)
    {
        var myPwdGuid = "Encrypted password by GUID";
        var myHostKey = "Some long Host key around 380 characters";

        // establish connection to remote FTP server
           var connection = sftp.createConnection({
            username: 'fuel_integration',
            passwordGuid: myPwdGuid, // references var myPwdGuid
            url: '59.165.215.45',//Example IP
            directory: '/sftproot/TaleoSync',
            restrictToScriptIds : runtime.getCurrentScript().id,
            restrictToCurrentUser :false,
            hostKey: myHostKey // references var myHostKey
           });
        // specify the file to upload using the N/file module

        // download the file from the remote server

        var downloadedFile = connection.download({
            directory: '/sftproot/TaleoSync',
            filename: 'Fuel Funnel Report_without filter.csv'
        });
        downloadedFile.folder = ;
        downloadedFile.save();

         context.response.write(' Downloaded "Fuel Funnel Report_without filter" to fileCabinet');

    }

    return {
        execute: execute
        };


});
```

I expect to create a connection between SFTP and NetSuite to down a file from SFTP and place it to NetSuite file cabinet.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

```
restrictToScriptIds : runtime.getCurrentScript().id,
restrictToCurrentUser :false,
```

Are not part of the createConnection signature. Those should have been used when you created a Suitelet to vault your credential.

However the hostkey complaint may be dealt with by using ssh-keyscan from a linux box.

```
ssh-keyscan  59.165.215.45
```

should replay with the server name then ssh-rsa then a long base64 string. Copy that string so it ends up in myHostKey and set the hostKeyType to RSA.