# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 SFTP - How to connect with private key

Tags: sftp, netsuite, private-key, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to create a script that connects to a vendor system using SFTP.

But instead of providing me the password, they sent me a private key file (.ppk).
I read some articles and following some instructions and I was able to convert it to '.pem' and import it to NetSuite on the Private Key page.

But now, I don't know how to load the key in the script and I couldn't find anything on the NS reference guide.

```
/********************* SFTP connection Logic *********************/ 
            
            var myPwdGuid = ''; //I don't know how to fill this field / No password was provided            
            var myHostKey ='' ;//I don't know how to fill this field
            
            var connection = sftp.createConnection({
                username: 'usr_ch_prd_client_CEN',
                passwordGuid: myPwdGuid,
                url: 'vendorserverurl',
                port: 22,
                hostKey: myHostKey,
                hostKeyType:'rsa'
            });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `passwordGuid` you need `keyId`

as for the host key see [FTP_INCORRECT_HOST_KEY in N/SFTP Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002506/ftp-incorrect-host-key-in-n-sftp-module)